# Using awstats with a round-robin DNS configuration

Tags: monitoring, awstats, web

I have a website with multiple web servers whose access is controlled via a round-robin DNS. We currently use Google Analytics for site traffic monitoring but were looking to move to awstats due to concerns of inaccuracy with Google Analytics and using third-party trackers in general.

I have a little experience with awstats and I know it gets its information from parsing server logs. How would this work when you have multiple web servers logging independently to separate locations? Is this supported with awstats? Is there an alternative I could use to track traffic activity directly on my servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience with awstats you will need to consolidate the logs in chronological order.  However, you only need to keep the data around until you have loaded it into awstats.  If you don't need immediate updates consider grabbing the rotated logs an merge them.  I believe awstats has a script to do the merge.

Comment: It would appear that you're referring to the 'logresolvemerge' tool found here: http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_tools.html#logresolvemerge

We wouldn't need up-to-the-minute accuracy on awstats, so rotating the logs once a day in conjunction with logresolvemerge would suit our purposes.